Identity verification at Google Play for a government org
Somewhat off-topic for SO, but I'll try. At Google Play, one is now expected to prove their identity - individual or corporate. I happen to manage an account for an organization within the United States federal government. The following policy line seems to describe what I'm expected to provide:

A dated letter requesting verification for a government or public agency, written on official agency letterhead

Who should write the letter? To whom it should be addressed? What should it say? It's not like any letter on the agency's letterhead would do - I've tried.
Calling my fellow government reps with corporate Google Play accounts. What was your proof of identity?

I'm in the same boat. This is utterly ridiculous. And do Google think I'm giving them MY driver license and passport just because I'm the poor schmuck developer who maintains the department's developer account? I don't think so.

I've got the verification.
I've obtained a copy of the general correspondence template from the team that's in charge of public communication. It was a fairly simple letterhead - black and white department logo, department name, agency name. I wrote a "To whom it may concern" letter on that letterhead, telling what we are, where are the headquarters, when and how were we established.
Just in case, I've attached a two page copy of the act of Congress that established our agency back in 1930es - not sure that was even needed, but it didn't hurt; I thought it was as close as it got to a business license. I've got those pages from a legislink.org link from the right sidebar of the act's page at Wikipedia.
And they took it.
